# Is there a way to iterate over a Dictionary of the form Key:[Value1:[Value2]]?

Tags: swift, loops, dictionary

I am trying to iterate over a Dictionary with a Key:[Value1:[Value2]] form.

Essentially, I am trying to iterate over the dictionary one item at a time.  However, I am only able to print the iteration in the form

Key

> (["Value1":[value2(0), value2(1), ..., value2(n)]]

where (0), (1), ..., (n) represent the n-th value of the value2 array

```
var col_read: [String: [String:[Double]]] = ["key":["value1":[value2]]]

//  array
var value2 = [Double]()

 for (key, value1, value1:[value2]) in col_read
    {
        print("\(key)\n\(value1)\n(value1:[value2])")
    }
```

I would like to print the iteration in the form

> Key
>
> Value1
>
> Value2(0)
>
> Value2(1)
>
> . . .
>
> Value2(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite plainly like this?

```
for (key, value) in col_read {
    print(key)
    for (innerKey, innerValue) in value {
        print(innerKey)
        for number in innerValue {
            print(number)
        }
    } 
}
```

---

**P.S** - Use *lowerCamelCase* for variable names as mentioned in the [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming).

Comment: awesome thank you!  I've spent hours trying to figure this out.. Thanks again!